# python/pandas - Transformed value_counts by Category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Category_1 | Category_2 | Category_3 | Category_4 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| a          | b          | b          | y          |
| a          | a          | c          | y          |
| c          | c          | c          | n          |
| b          | b          | c          | n          |
| a          | a          | a          | y          |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I'm hoping for a pivot_table like result, with the counts of the frequency for each category. Something like this:

```
+---+------------+----+----+----+
|   |            | a  | b  | c  |
+---+------------+----+----+----+
|   | Category_1 | 12 | 10 | 40 |
| y | Category_2 | 15 | 48 | 26 |
|   | Category_3 | 10 |  2 |  4 |
|   | Category_1 |  5 |  6 |  4 |
| n | Category_2 |  9 |  5 |  2 |
|   | Category_3 |  8 |  4 |  3 |
+---+------------+----+----+----+
```

I know I could pull it off by splitting the table, assigning value_counts to column values, then rejoining. Is there any more simple, more 'pythonic' way of pulling this off? I figure it may along the lines of a pivot paired with a Transform, but tests so far have been ugly at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we need to `melt` (or `stack` ) your original dataframe, then we doing `pd.crosstab`, you can using `pd.pivot_table` as well.

```
s=df.set_index('Category_4').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'value'})
pd.crosstab([s.Category_4,s.level_1],s['value'])
Out[532]: 
value                  a  b  c
Category_4 level_1            
n          Category_1  0  1  1
           Category_2  0  1  1
           Category_3  0  0  2
y          Category_1  3  0  0
           Category_2  2  1  0
           Category_3  1  1  1
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! So if I understand correctly: setting the index (so it doesn't get caught up in the stack,) stack to move columns into rows, then crosstab (which defaults to counts) on 2 column types?

Comment: @iamthestarlord yep, you got it

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `get_dummies` first, then summing across index levels

```
d = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Category_4'))
d.columns = d.columns.str.rsplit('_', 1, True)
d = d.stack(0)

# This shouldn't be necessary but is because the
# index gets bugged and I'm "resetting" it
d.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.index.values)

d.sum(level=[0, 1])

              a  b  c
y Category_1  3  0  0
  Category_2  2  1  0
  Category_3  1  1  1
n Category_1  0  1  1
  Category_2  0  1  1
  Category_3  0  0  2
```